# Scroll bar has not showing up

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

[I'm having a trouble with no scroll bar showing up on my page when I resized the web page. this page was built up with bootstrap and used CDN as an option to install, so i have nothing to do with the css, any help would be highly appreciated, thank you so much](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1UEj.png)

the code--

```html
   

    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="id">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>attor - Hukum lebih mudah dengan attor</title>

      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <!-- Optional theme -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container-fluid">

            <!-- logo -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">attor</a>
            </div>

            <!-- menu items -->
            <div>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Direktori attor</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>

                  <!-- dropdown menus -->
                  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">FAQ <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">For client</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">For attorney</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Cara kerja</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign in</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- jumbotron -->
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
              <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
              <p>lorem ispsum dolor sit amet.</p>
              <p a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Start now</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Why<small>attor?</small></h1>
          </div>


          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: add code otherwise it will be closed

Comment: we understand your querstion but we can not help when we not see your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had few mark-up error in your code--you forgot to close the `nav` and `head` tag.

**now working fine**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="id">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>attor - Hukum lebih mudah dengan attor</title>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  .jumbotron {
    height: 1000px;
  }
</style>
</head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- logo -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">attor</a>
        </div>

        <!-- menu items -->
        <div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Direktori attor</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>

              <!-- dropdown menus -->
              <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">FAQ <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">For client</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">For attorney</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Cara kerja</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign in</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</nav>
      <!-- jumbotron -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
          <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
          <p>lorem ispsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <p a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Start now</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Why<small>attor?</small></h1>
      </div>


     
     
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: really appreciate that, no more better than to say thankyou @neophyte .it was so intimidating at first to be a newcomer. thanks once again

Comment: if it has helped please accept the answer..Welcome to SO..in SO if a answer helps we upvote it and if the answer solves your problem we accept it ..that's how SO works and it prevents spam answers.